# Reoccurring Error Message

Tags: error

We are getting this error:

> Uncaught Action failed: ui$inputSelect$controller$doInit [TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'Salutation' of null]

Can anyone help in fixing this error?

Comment: Please share your code, so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this error message is due to a recent known issue in salesforce.com Summer 16 Release.

Reference : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000184YVQAY

And as for the work-around, it looks like there isn't any.